# How to do the dynamic precision from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Currency with Precision.

```
Currency Precision InstituteId
KWD      2         1 
QAR      3         2
```

I have another table (Receipt)

```
CustomerName Amount(numeric(18,2)) InstituteId
Ahemda       100.00                1
Nirava       200.00                2
```

I want output like this

```
select Amount  from Receipt where InstituteId = 1

output : 100.00

select Amount from Receipt where InstituteId = 2

output : 200.000
```

Decimal points display as per currency wise ...please give me suggestions.is there any direct function or any implicit conversation ?

Comment: sql server has a [`money`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) data type you might find useful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(FLOOR(r.[Amount]) AS varchar(18)) + 
    SUBSTRING(CAST(CAST(r.[Amount] AS numeric(18, 10)) - FLOOR(r.[Amount]) AS varchar(18)), 2, c.[Precision] + 1) AS [Amount]
FROM 
    [Receipt] AS r
    INNER JOIN
    [Currency] c ON r.[InstituteId] = c.[InstituteId]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and above you can use [`FORMAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) like this

```
DECLARE @Value NUMERIC(18,2)= 100.0

;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT 2 as Precision UNION ALL SELECT 3
)
SELECT FORMAT(@Value,'.' + REPLICATE('0',Precision)) as value
FROM CTE
```

**Output**

```
value
100.00
100.000
```

In your case it would be

```
SELECT FORMAT(Amount ,'.' + REPLICATE('0',Precision)) as value
FROM Receipt R inner join Currency C on R.InstituteId = C.InstituteId
```